# How do I remove the space at the bottom of the page(chrome extension)?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

[image: This is what my extension looks like]

How can I remove the ugly white space at the bottom under the radio buttons? There is nothing in the code that could be causing it, I'll post it if you'd like.
Thanks!

ANSWER: 
Im not sure why, but if you change `<html>` to `<!doctype html>` it fixes the problem! :D

Comment: See if any of the comments [here](http://groups.google.com/group/chromium-extensions/browse_thread/thread/57b70e79fa1d1693) helps.

Comment: answered my own question, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A discussion on the issue and some solutions are available [here](http://groups.google.com/group/chromium-extensions/browse_thread/thread/57b70e79fa1d1693).