# Chrome Extension Popup is too high when first click

Tags: google-chrome-extension

as I found out a few days ago when you click an extension button and popup shows up, its height is much higher than it needs to be if you need the height to be less than 350px. When something happens in the popup (animation e.g.) the height is adjusted properly according to the content. Setting height to html, body and general wrapper element didn't help. It might be some bug in the latest update of Chrome, I cannot test it in earlier builds, because of autoupdate.

I'll be thankful for any thoughts and advices.

Libor

**UPDATE:** I started to examine what can possibly cause this behaviour and found out this happens because of Twitter and Google Plus share buttons. They both modify DOM structure adding script tag which adds iframe. When commented, popup bubble appeared in correct size. The weird thing is facebook like button script does more or less the same, but it doesn't mess up the layout at all.

Comment: Is your problem same as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360525/how-do-i-remove-the-space-at-the-bottom-of-the-pagechrome-extension/10360784#10360784)?

Comment: very much the same, but chrome started to behave this way after the last update so i dont think it should be related in any way

Answer (score 4):

Like it was said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360525/how-do-i-remove-the-space-at-the-bottom-of-the-pagechrome-extension/10360784#10360784), the good solution to solve this problem is changing `<html> to <!doctype html>`

Comment: This fixed the popup height jankiness for me. Thanks!

Comment: I had an issue where the first click of a href link wasn't changing the page in my extension. Add !doctype to the html tag seemed to work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing here with my extension and Chrome 19 on Windows 7. I must note that there were no problems with the previous version of Chrome. As you stated the issue shows up only on the first appearance of the popup - it shrinks correctly afterwards).

I'm using jQuery in my extension and I think I've partially solved it by adding

```
    $("body").fadeOut(10).fadeIn(50);
```

though it doesn't always work (it probably will if you increment the fadeIn delay but!). Hope someone can provide a better solution to this.

**EDIT.** This *should* be guaranteed to always work (using your hint) although the user might see the resizing happening for a fraction of second:

```
    $(window).load(function() { 
        $("body").fadeOut(10, function() { $(this).show(); }); 
    });
```

Comment: thank you, this did the trick, although i believe the correct syntax should be $('body').fadeOut(500, function() { $(this).show() }); e.g.

Comment: Removing the share icons doesn't seem to work for me. I've edited my post and added some code that provides more consistent results. Still looking for a final solution though.